# Why does formatting the secondary axis result in an error?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2007, vba

I've created a function that creates charts from data arrays. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't, for unclear reasons. If it doesn't, it gives the following error:

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'

I've tried to reduce the code as much as possible while still 'conserving' the problem. The reduced code is below. It errors on the third line from below. If the DoEvents statement is used on the indicated position, it errors much less often, but still sometimes. I'm using Excel 2007.

My questions are:

1. What is the problem here?
2. What to do about it, as adding DoEvents is not a complete solution. Also, I've read that DoEvents is often considered quite evil.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim a(1 To 3) As Double
Dim b(1 To 3) As Double
Dim c(1 To 3) As Double
Dim d(1 To 3) As Double

a(1) = 1.1
a(2) = 1.3
a(3) = 0.8

b(1) = 1.1
b(2) = 1.3
b(3) = 0.8

c(1) = 1.1
c(2) = 1.3
c(3) = 0.8

d(1) = 1.1
d(2) = 1.3
d(3) = 0.8

Call PrintSimChart(a, b, c, d)

End Sub

Function PrintSimChart(a() As Double, b() As Double, c() As Double, d() As Double)
'Prints given simulation result to chart

Dim SimChart As Chart
'Create a new chart.
Set SimChart = Charts.Add

With SimChart

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        .Values = a
        .XValues = b
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    End With

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        .Values = c
        .XValues = d
'        DoEvents 'Not adding this line causes a crash on line:   .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .Format.Line.Weight = 1
    End With

    .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

    .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

End With
End Function
```

Comment: `Also, I've read that DoEvents is often considered quite evil.` Where have you read that? If adding `Doevents` solves the problem then you should exactly do that. It simply means that excel needs few moments to finish the last operation that you requested for.

Comment: Since you have not set .AxisGroup for the added series it defaults to the primary group. I'm not sure why you are formatting a secondary category axis. Perhaps just delete that line of code.

Comment: A google search on 'DoEvents' yields some results in which the dangers of DoEvents are described. I don't have experience with the command, and would like comments on whether or not it is appropriate to use it here. In my original code, I've been adding them everywhere, solving the problem in most of the cases, but the problem keeps popping up randomly and also when small other (seemingly insignificant) changes to the code are made.

Comment: @pnuts Hi, please see what I mean in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

This is the minimal solution that I found that works reliably.  Two extra lines were required to fix the problem.

```
Function PrintSimChart(a() As Double, b() As Double, c() As Double, d() As Double)
'Prints given simulation result to chart

Dim SimChart As Chart
'Create a new chart.
Set SimChart = Charts.Add

With SimChart

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .Values = a
        .XValues = b
    End With

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .Values = c
        .XValues = d
        .AxisGroup = xlSecondary   '**Required Edit**
        .Format.Line.Weight = 1
    End With
    With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .CategoryType = xlTimeScale
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With

    .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlSecondary) = True   '**Required Edit**
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With

End Function
```

Comment: The second with-block in my code adds a new series and a second set of axes (at least it does with the DoEvents statement). I want to format the labels of that set. Deleting the suggested line won't solve my problem.

Comment: first of all: Thank you for your efforts. Unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't work (even with the DoEvents statement it doesn't), but I think you're onto something. On stepping through, I noticed that on the line `.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers` a second horizontal and vertical axis is added. You're suggestion `.AxisGroup = xlSecondary` prevents that somehow, by only adding a vertical axis. Stepping through the code slowly mostly works, so I guess it has something to do with certain commands not finishing quickly enough to be used later. But how to solve that?

Comment: I'm sure we can solve it, but first of all I go back to my original thought and ask: do you really need a second horizontal axis with a separate XValues series?  I mean are your arrays b and d fundamentally different?  Its hard to tell from your data coz I guess its just example data as its all the same...

Comment: You're right, its example data. The thing is, in my original problem, I  plot 5 data series in one graph. 2 of them are column graphs, and 3 are scatter graphs. I believe I need a set of axes for both, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What happens if you comment this line out in the second with block? .XValues = d... oh, and comment this one out as well of course: .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"...b and d WILL have the same data right?

Comment: 4 of my 5 data sets share the same .xValues, the last one has a different .xValues array. You're suggestion works, but I don't think it is usable in the original problem (although you couldn't have known this).

Comment: OK, maybe take a look at the Axis.CategoryType property, try setting it to xlTimeScale. Also, try setting the chart type before the series and clear with doevents after each step.

Comment: Ah OK, I see you are setting category type implicitly.  Its probably only setting it for the primary axis. Maybe set the Axis.CategoryType property to xlTimeScale for both groups explicitly.

Comment: I'm afraid the actual problem seems to far away from the example I gave . I realized that in the process. Thanks for all the comments, because they've helped me! I'll vote some up. If I start a new question that is closer to my actual problem I'll post the link here.

Comment: Well, the problem is reproducible so we should post a solution for future reference. I have updated my answer with a solution that works...